# $P$ is a prime ideal, and $ R/P$ has no nilpotent elements. Then $R/P$ is a domain.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra, integral-domain, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> Let $P$ be a prime ideal. Suppose that  $R/P$  has no nonzero nilpotent elements. Show that $R/P$ is a domain.

What I did :

WTS : $(a+P)(b+P)=ab+P=0+P$ implies $a+P=0+P$ or $b+P=0+P$.

but it means that $ab \in P$ implies $a \in P$ or $ b \in P$. The nilpotent condition means that $a \notin R $ implies $a^n \notin R$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Since P is a prime, $AB \subseteq P $ implies $A \subseteq P$ or $B \subseteq P$ for ideals $A,B$ in a ring $R$. To use this, I made ideals $(a),(b),(ab)$.

It suffices show that $(a)(b) \subseteq P$ but I failed to show this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Am I misremembering? Isn't the quotient ring after modding out by a prime ideal *always* an integral domain? And I feel like you even showed this... since $a\in P$ implies $a+P=0+P$.

Comment: @Guillermo : If you are working in a commutative ring, then Clayton is right, this is always true.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan: Ahha, perhaps that is what I'm recalling; if it is in a commutative ring. All of my work has been only in commutative rings, so I believe I am prone to make that mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the ways we characterize prime ideals is as follows:

> For any elements $a$ and $b$ of $R$, if $aRb \subseteq P$, then $a \in P$ or $b \in P$.

Suppose $P$ is a prime ideal and $R/P$ has no nonzero nilpotent elements. Suppose $$\overline a \overline b = (a + P)(b + P) = ab + P = 0 + P = \overline 0.$$

Let $r \in R$ be arbitrary and consider $$(\overline{bra})^2 = (\overline{bra})(\overline{bra}) = \overline{br}(\overline{ab})\overline{ra} =  \overline{br}(\overline 0)\overline{ra} = \overline 0.$$

Since $R/P$ has no nonzero nilpotent elements, $\overline {bra} = \overline0$ which means $bra \in P$ for all $r \in R$. Thus $bRa \subseteq P$ which means $a \in P$ or $b \in P$ by the definition of prime ideal.

Therefore $\overline a = \overline 0$ or $\overline b = \overline 0$.

Some references:

1. [Exercises in Classical Ring Theory](http://books.google.com/books?id=S3pZbAByfDgC&pg=PA143#v=onepage&q&f=false) - T. Y. Lam
2. [About Reduced Rings](http://ysharifi.wordpress.com/2010/06/04/about-reduced-rings-1/)